# How to put a loop into string php?

Tags: php, arrays, string

This code for the body of email that i want to send...so i want to loop for the name so i will display like this name abu,name ali,name rajesh

```
  $z = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT name FROM usr where usr_id=:num1");
oci_bind_by_name($z, ":num1",$INIT);
oci_execute($z);
$row = oci_fetch_row($z);
           $MERC_HAND_USR_ID_name[]=$row[0];

       }

$body='Dear Helpdesk Manager

     We would like to inform that a new report has been made by.

    Name:   '.foreach($MERC_HAND_USR_ID_name as $key => $value)
    {
       $value;

    }.'

    date:  '. $date.'
    time:  '. $time.'

    Thank You,

    - Helpdesk ';
```

it is possible for me to do like this or there is other way?

Comment: Control statements (your `foreach`) can't be concated to a string directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.

```
$body='Dear Helpdesk Manager

We would like to inform that a new report has been made by.';
foreach($MERC_HAND_USR_ID_name as $key => $value)
{
    $body.= '<br> &nbsp Name:   '.$value;
}
$body.='
<br><br>
date:  '.date("Y/m/d").'
<br>
time:  '. date("h:i:sa").'
<br><br>Thank You,<br><br>- Helpdesk ';
```

Comment: tq for helping it work charmly.... i need to learn more for understanding the code

Answer (score 1):

You must change your $body variable like below

```
$body='Dear Helpdesk Manager

 We would like to inform that a new report has been made by.

';
foreach($MERC_HAND_USR_ID_name as $key => $value)
{
  $body .= 'Name: ' . $value . ' ';

}
$body .= '

date:  '. $date.'
time:  '. $time.'

Thank You,

- Helpdesk ';
```

Since you have to loop through $MERC_HAND_USR_ID_name, you must prepare the mail body by appending it in your foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a loop inside a string.
You need to create a string with your names first and then concatenate it with the $body string.

Something like this:

```
$z = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT name FROM usr where usr_id=:num1");
oci_bind_by_name($z, ":num1",$INIT);
oci_execute($z);
$row = oci_fetch_row($z);
$MERC_HAND_USR_ID_name[]=$row[0];

//} // ==> This closes nothing

$names = '';

foreach($MERC_HAND_USR_ID_name as $key => $value) {
    $name .= 'Name: ' . $value; //here you can manipulate it however you want... like maybe add a space between values (. ' ') or a line break (<br/>)
}

$body='Dear Helpdesk Manager
       We would like to inform that a new report has been made by '. 
       $name .
       'date:  '. $date .
       'time:  '. $time.
       'Thank You,
       - Helpdesk ';
```

Comment: sry i have question to ask about this $name .= 'Name: ' . $value; what need to put . before = why does do like this $name =. 'Name: ' . $value;

Comment: Hi Jens, the "." in front of the "=" just means add this to the variable. It's the short way of writing $name = $name . 'Name: ' . $value;